how to combine array of map in a single map per column in pyspark
i have followed this question but the answers there not working for me
i don't want a UDF for this and map_concat doesn't work for me.
is there any other way to combine maps?
eg



id
value




1
Map(k1 -> v1)


2
Map(k2 -> v2)



output should be



id
value




1
Map(k1 -> v1, k2 -> v2)




Here is my solution, I'm assuming that we can drop id
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()

data = [{'id':1, 'map':{'k1': 'v1'}}, {'id':2, 'map':{'k2': 'v2'}}, {'id':3, 'map':{'k3': 'v3'}}]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

# removing id , adding grouping column
d_df = df.drop('id').withColumn('group_id', f.lit(1)) 

# aggregating into array of maps
g_df = d_df.groupBy('group_id')\
    .agg(f.collect_list('map').alias('maps'))

# concating the maps
final_df = g_df.select(f.aggregate('maps', f.create_map().cast("map<string,string>"), lambda acc, i: f.map_concat(acc, i)).alias('map_of_maps'))
final_df.show()

Result:
+--------------------+
|         map_of_maps|
+--------------------+
|{k1 -> v1, k2 -> ...|
+--------------------+

